# Know what device in flash builder for mobile

Tags: iphone, flash, flash-builder

I'm doing an application for mobile devices, specifically for iphone and ipad. And I want to use different interfaces for each. How can I do that? Is there a variable that holds the name of the device?
Such as

```
if(device=="iPhone")
    {use this state}
else if (device=="iPad")
    {use that state}
```

??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Capabilities.os`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html#os) to obtain the device's operating system and see if it uses iOS, then use [`Capabilities.screenResolutionX`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html#screenResolutionX) and [`Capabilities.screenResolutionY`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html#screenResolutionY) to determine if the resolutions correspond to an iPhone or an iPad.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this document](http://blogs.adobe.com/flashplatform/2011/04/mobile-development-scaling-content-depending-on-the-screen-resolution.html) which shows general principles for scaling things based on the screen resolution.

It is not an exact answer to your question but I am guessing that you just want to scale your interfaces based on the screen resolution.

You can also check the screen DPI using `Capabilities.screenDPI.` which is nice to know how spread out those pixels are along with `Capabilities.screenResolutionX` and `Capabilities.screenResolutionY` to get the resolution.

If you really want to know what the operating system is you can check using `Capabilities.os`, but as for an exact device I'm not sure if there is a method for that.